# how to make my flashlight not o open instantly when i open the program?

Tags: flashlight

```
    // Get the camera
        private void getCamera() {
            if (camera == null) {
                try {
                    camera = Camera.open();
                    params = camera.getParameters();
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }





// Turning On flash
    private void turnOnFlash() {
        if (!isFlashOn) {
            if (camera == null || params == null) {
                return;
            }
        // play sound
        playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;

        // changing button/switch image
        toggleButtonImage();
    }

}
```

My code that gets involved with flash on is above, any suggestions,how to make the flash not open the moment my app opens but only when i press the button

Comment: So where in your code is `turnFlashOn()` getting called from?

Comment: can't u help me with that? :/

Comment: No, because you didn't include code anywhere that calls `turnFlashOn()`. If you had, I wouldn't have asked where the call was coming from. :-) Search your code, and find out where `turnFlashOn()` is being called (not **defined**, but **called**).

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you are calling `turnFlashOn()` in `onCreate()` and don't have a button ClickListener. But it is possible you could be calling `turnFlashOn()` in `onStart()` or `onResume()`.

To have it turn on with a button press you should do something like

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_view);

    flashlight_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button);
    flashlight_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getCamera();
            turnOnFlash();
        }
    });

}
```

I built an open source flashlight for Android that you can check out at [Flashlight by Joe github](https://github.com/jbutewicz/Flashlight-by-Joe).